# 仮想空間でPILをインストールしたい

Tags: python, tensorflow, pil

tensorflowの仮想空間のJupyter notebookでfrom PIL import Imageとした所エラーが出ました

PILをインストールすればいいのかと思いターミナルでsouce activateでtensorflowに移りpip install PILと打ち込んだんですがエラーになります

仮想空間でライブラリをインストールしたい場合はどうすればいいでしょうか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PILはもうメンテナンスされていない(からバージョンが合わずエラーになる)ので、フォークライブラリのPillowをインストールしましょう。

`pip install Pillow`

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/4.2.1